# Mongo user exist validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to perform a sign up form into `Mongo` `Node.js` and `Express.js`. I have already completed the task which inserts a document into users collection for a new user. But I need to create a validation if a user exist based on username or email as keys.

For example I am submitting a user:
`{  "_id": {    "$oid": "62ac54c4cd1c80d0e8e2f68a"  },  "firstName": "test",  "lastName": "test",  "email": "test@test.com",  "password": "test",  "username": "test"}`

If I try to sumbit the same creds in the sign up form, my API completely crashes with error code:

```
db.collection(...).exists is not a function
```

***Note**: I am using mongoose*

Code:

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const username = req.body.username;

    var data = {
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "username": username
    }

    console.log(data);

    let userExist = await db.collection('users').exists({ "username": username, "email": email })
    console.log(userExist);

    if (userExist) {
        console.log("User already exists");
        return res.render('login');
    } else {
        db.collection('users').insertOne(data, function (err, collection) {if (err) throw err;});
    }
    res.render('login', { 'data': data });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to use mongodb try to implement with mongoose.
Here is link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

Comment: You are not using `mongoose` if you are executing queries with `db.collection(...)`. Can you post the code where you initialize the `db` instance?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to find  if user exists in the collection via two fields which are `username` and `email`.

With mongoose you could actually do it in many ways and the most better approach is to define your model, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

If you want to stick with your case then you could try this:

```
db.collection('users').find({ "username": username, "email": email })
```